# Using Azure AD as a authentication provider for Azure B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-service-fabric, azure-ad-b2c

I have an angular-cli (v8) web application where I want users to be able to sign-in using their existing Azure AD account.

I came across the article explaining how to added authentication to an angular 8 application using Azure B2C and started to follow the step outlined in that article. https://about-azure.com/using-azure-ad-b2c-with-angular-8/

Azure AD is not on the list of authentication providers 
[image]

Is is possible to add Azure AD as an authentication provider?

Technically my application is an Service Fabric application using .net core 3.1. I know that Visual Studio offers and "Add Connect Services" where one can choose Azure AD.

That does not work, because it configures authentication for a MVC application (options use.MVC) and I do not have an MVC application so it doesn't work (I have tried)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is is possible to add Azure AD as an authentication provider?

Yes, you need to select **New OpenID Connect provider** and configure Azure AD as an identity provider.

[image]

Reference:

[Set up sign-in for a specific Azure Active Directory organization in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant)